# How the Jordan Schwinger components transform the mode operators in a Beam Splitter- component

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, quantum-optics

[image: Equation from "Essential Quantum Optics by Ulf Leonhardt]

Hello,

I am unsure how to prove this equation. It is suggested to take the derivative with respect to theta on both sides and use commutation relations for the Jordan Schwinger operators.

I can't see how this method will remove the L_y operator from the exponent. I would usually try to Taylor expand this and then use the commutation relations in hope of removing the operator from the exponent, but that is not suggested.

For clarity, the annihilation operators are Bosonic, and the Jordan Schwinger operators are also attatched:

[image: J-S operators: "Essential Quantum Optics by Ulf Leonhardt]

Thank you for any advice!

Answer (score 1):

Denote 
$$
\hat a_i(\Theta) = e^{-i\Theta \hat{L}_y} \hat{a}_i e^{i\Theta \hat{L}_y} 
$$
and notice that
$$
\frac{d\hat a_i}{d\Theta} = -i\; e^{-i\Theta \hat{L}_y} [L_y,\hat{a}_i] e^{i\Theta \hat{L}_y} 
$$
where 
$$
[\hat L_y, \hat a_1] = \frac{i}{2}[\hat a_2^\dagger \hat a_1 - \hat a_1^\dagger \hat a_2, \hat a_1] = \frac{i}{2}\hat a_2\\
\;[\hat L_y, \hat a_2] = \frac{i}{2}[\hat a_2^\dagger \hat a_1 - \hat a_1^\dagger \hat a_2, \hat a_2] =  -\frac{i}{2}\hat a_1
$$
This gives explicitly
$$
\frac{d\hat a_1}{d\Theta} = \frac{1}{2} \hat a_2(\Theta)\\
\frac{d\hat a_2}{d\Theta} = - \frac{1}{2} \hat a_1(\Theta)
$$
and in matrix form,
$$
\frac{d}{d\Theta} \left( \begin{array}{c} \hat a_1 \\ \hat a_2 \end{array} \right) = \frac{i}{2} \left( \begin{array}{cc} 0 & -i \\ i & 0 \end{array} \right)\left( \begin{array}{c} \hat a_1 \\ \hat a_2 \end{array} \right)
$$
The solution is immediate,
$$
\left( \begin{array}{c} \hat a_1 \\ \hat a_2 \end{array} \right) = e^{\frac{i\Theta}{2}\hat \sigma_y}\left( \begin{array}{c} \hat a_1 \\ \hat a_2 \end{array} \right)
$$
and if the matrix exponential is replaced by its explicit form, the expressions for the $\hat a_i(\Theta)$-s follow.

---

Just for fun, the same expressions can be obtained using the [Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#An_important_lemma):

$$
e^{\hat X} \hat{Y} e^{-\hat X} = \hat{Y} + [\hat{X}, \hat{Y}] + \frac{1}{2!}[\hat{X},[\hat{X}, \hat{Y}]] + \frac{1}{3!}[\hat{X},[\hat{X},[\hat{X}, \hat{Y}]]] + ...
$$
In your case take $\hat X = -i\Theta \hat{L}_y$, $\hat Y = \hat a_1$ and $\hat Y = \hat a_2$ successively, and notice that the resulting series are easily recognizable. For instance: 
$$
e^{-i\Theta \hat{L}_y} \hat{a}_1 e^{i\Theta \hat{L}_y} = \hat a_1 - i\Theta \;[\hat L_y, \hat a_1] + \frac{(-i\Theta)^2}{2!} \;[\hat L_y,[\hat L_y, \hat a_1]] + \\
+ \frac{(-i\Theta)^3}{3!} \;[\hat L_y,[\hat L_y,[\hat L_y, \hat a_1]]]  + \frac{(-i\Theta)^4}{4!} \;[\hat L_y,[\hat L_y,[\hat L_y,[\hat L_y, \hat a_1]]]] \;+ ... =\\
= \hat a_1 + (\Theta/2)\hat a_2 - \frac{(\Theta/2)^2}{2!}\hat a_1 - \frac{(\Theta/2)^3}{3!} \hat a_2 + \frac{(\Theta/2)^4}{4!} \hat a_1 + ... = \\ = \sum_{n=0}^\infty{\frac{(-1)^n(\Theta/2)^{2n}}{(2n)!}\hat a_1} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty{\frac{(-1)^n(\Theta/2)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\hat a_2} =\\
= \cos\left( \frac{\Theta}{2}\right)\hat a_1 + \sin\left( \frac{\Theta}{2}\right) \hat a_2
$$

Similarly for $e^{-i\Theta \hat{L}_y} \hat{a}_2 e^{i\Theta \hat{L}_y}$, etc.